# is it possible to get the specific Teams contacts list of a user?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-teams

I've searched a lot and apparently with the Microsoft Graph API we can get the organization contacts/users list and the default contacts list of a user across Office 365 as well, but I am afraid I won't be able to get the specific Teams list of contacts of a user

Can someone please confirm this to me and perhaps give me suggestions of some other alternative?